# What is the difference between Sprint and Iteration in Scrum and length of each Sprint?

Tags: agile, scrum, iteration, methodology, sprint

1. Is there a difference between Sprint and an Iteration or one can have Iterations within a Sprint or Sprint is just the terminology used instead of Iteration in Scrum? It will be helpful if someone can throw some light on this.
2. Suppose there are 4 sprints and you have decided the first sprint will go up to 10 days is it required that other 3 sprints should have the same length of the 1st decided sprint's length??.

Comment: This is not the Scrum way, but it is healthier to stop using the word sprint and replace it with the word iteration. The word sprint implies you are going as fast as humanly possible, because that is what sprinters do. But when one sprint ends, the next one begins, which implies everyone should be pushing themselves to the extreme all day, every day. But that is not a helpful impression to put into peoples heads, as it is not what you intend to or should do. The term iteration is more appropriate. It implies you will keep iterating, which is closer to the primary purpose of a sprint.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 https://twitter.com/timhc22/status/1281249714164453377?s=20

Answer (score 68, accepted):

All sprints are iterations but not all iterations are sprints. Iteration is a common term in iterative and incremental development (IID). Scrum is one specialized flavor of IID so it makes sense to specialize the terminology as well. It also helps brand the methodology different from other IID methodologies :)

As to the sprint length: anything goes as long as the sprint is timeboxed i.e. it is finished on the planned date and not "when it's ready". (Or alternatively, in rare occasions, the sprint is terminated prematurely to start a new sprint in case some essential boundary conditions are changed.)

It does help to have the sprints of similar durations. There's less to remember about the sprint schedule and your planning gets more accurate. I like to keep mine at 2 calendar weeks, which will resolve into 8..10 business days outside holiday seasons.

Comment: Its correct to say that an iteration can contains one or more sprint. For exampole we can have a sprint of a week ad an iteration of a week. Also, we could have an'iteration of a month and 3 sprint inside this iteration.

Comment: @sensorario: From my experience Iaalto's "equality" of iteration and sprint is what I would say is a good short hand definition. That being said how comes you would say a sprint his "higher level" (containing iterations)? I think you could indeed have some sort of hierarchy as you say, but then a "sprint" is not related to Scrum anymore, since Scrum simply doesn't use this term in this way.

Answer (score 13):

Sprint == Iteration.

The lengths can vary, but it's a bad planning precedent to let them vary too much.

Keep them consistent in duration and you will get better at planning and delivering.  Everything will be measured by how many 10-day sprints it takes to finish a series of use cases.

Keep them consistent in length and you can plan your deliveries, end-user testing, etc., with more accuracy.

The point is to release on time at a consistent pace.  A regular schedule makes management slightly simpler and more predictable.

Comment: Sprint lengths for a specific project should always be consistent, the advantages that consistency brings (which you refer to) are virtually impossible to achieve otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The important thing about a sprint is that: within a sprint the functionality that is to be delivered is fixed.

A sprint is normally an iteration. But you can for example have a 4 week sprint, but have 4 one week "internal" iterations within that sprint.

There is a lot of discussion about the length of sprints. I think that if you do it according to the book they should all be the same length.

We have found that a short first sprint to get the development environment up and running, followed by longer basic functionality sprints, then short sprints towards the end of the project, has worked for us.

Answer (score 3):

"___ is largely an organizational issue caused by long hours, little down time, and continual peer, customer, and superior surveillance"

No this is not the definition of scrum, it is the wikipedia excerpt on the definition of burnout.

Dont do too many short 10 days sprints. You will burnout your team eventually. Use short sprints where you really need them, and don't do too many in a row. Think long-term. A distance runner always paces themselves for the full race and does sprints in short distances only where it matters.

If you burnout your team you can toss out all them fancy scrum charts, they won't do a thing for your team's plummeting productivity.

Comment: What the hell are you saying here? Many teams do use 2 weeks sprint. Yes, a sprint is intense, but this certainly doesn't mean people are working 80 hours per week, that's ridiculous. Why would people get burned out with two weeks sprints? Your answer sounds totally wrong.

Comment: Based on experience, most managers don't leave any slack or special do something else breaks in a 2 wk sprints, most try to maximize thinking it makes them look like better managers. For tiny or small projects that complete and people move on, it's one thing but supporting and enhancing products that never end  year after year, it's another matter. Continual 2wk sprints on never-ending projects gives one the feeling of a rat running on a wheel in a cage. My point is, in long-term projects is continual 2wk sprint really necessary?? I don't believe that it is.

Comment: My second point is just because a lot of people use continual 2wk sprints doesn't make it right. In silicon valley I see many companies calling a simple mirco-managing of developers with daily stand-ups on 2 week dev cycles SCRUM, even though they have no idea what what scrum process actually is.

Comment: I wish I could +1 your answer twice.

Answer (score 2):

Iteration is synonymous with sprint, sprint is just the Scrum terminology.

On the question about sprint length, the only caution I would note is that in Scrum you are using the past sprints to gain a level of predictability on your teams ability to deliver on their commitments for the sprint.  They do this by developing a velocity over a number of sprints.  A change in the team members or the length of the sprint are factors that will affect the velocity for a sprint, over past sprints.

Just as background, velocity is the sum of estimation points assigned to the backlog items, or stories, that were completely finished during that sprint.  Most Agile proponents (Mike Cohn, Ken Schwaber and Jeff Sutherland for instance), recommend that teams use "the recent weather" to base their future estimations on how much they think they can commit to in a sprint.  This means using the average from the last few sprints as the basis for an estimate in the upcoming sprint planning session.

Once again, varying the sprint length reduces your teams ability to provide that velocity statistic which the team uses for sprint planning, and the product owner uses for release planning (i.e. predicting when the project will end or what will be in the project at the end).

I recommend [Mike Cohn's book on Agile Estimating and Planning](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/books/1-agile-estimating-and-planning) to provide an overview of the way sprints, estimation and planning all can fit together.

Answer (score 2):

1. Where I work we have 2 Sprints to an Iteration.  The Iteration demo is before the business stakeholders that don't want to meet after every Sprint, but that is our interpretation of the terminology.  Some places may have the terms having equally meaning, I'm just pointing out that where I work they aren't the same thing.
2. No, sprints can have varying lengths.  Where I work we had a half a Sprint to align our Sprints with the Iterations that others in the project from another department were using.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sprint is just the term for an iteration.
2. You can change the Sprint length to be anything you want, but likely you'll want to try to find an amount of time that "works well" (which may mean any number of things for your team) and end up sticking with it over time.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience

1. Sprint is a kind of Iteration and one can have many Iterations within a
   single Sprint (e.g. one shall startover or iterate a task if it's
   failed and still having extra estimated time) or across many Sprints
   (such as performing ongoing tasks).
2. Normally, the duration for a Sprint can be one or two weeks, It
   depends on the time required and the priority of tasks (which could
   be defined by Product Owner or Scrum Master or the team) from the Product
   Backlog.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)

Answer (score -2):

Sprint as defined in pure Scrum has the duration 30 calendar days. However Iteration length could be anything as defined by the team.

Comment: Actually, the sprint duration is 30 days **or less**.